# Best way to store .resx string in an object?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

In my application I added the multilanguage support following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1) documentation.

Now I'm facing an issue: I need to translate also some javascript plugins, so I need to use the `.resx` string inside the `js` logic:

[image]

For access to those strings I can use the `IStringLocalizer` in the specific controller, let's suppose that the string above are part of `UserController`, I can access declaring in the `View` this:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<UserController> Localizer
```

and then:

```
<h2>@Localizer["LastName"]</h2>
```

Suppose now that I need to pass `LastName` string in something like a `JQuery` plugin
localization. For doing so, I actually found a workaround, which consists to declare a `javascript` variable in the required `View`:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<UserController> Localizer

@section UserScript{
<script>
    var Lang = {
        PasswordEqual: '@Localizer["PasswordEqual"]',
        PasswordMismatch: '@Localizer["PasswordMismatch"]',
   }
</script>
```

}

so I can access inside the `javascript` code to the `Lang` object and localize the plugin eg:

```
 $('#birthDate').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    locale: {
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        daysOfWeek: [
           Lang.Sunday,
           Lang.Monday,
```

This works, but it's really huge to mantain for the following reason:

- I need to declare in each `.cshtml` file which require a `script` localization the `Lang` object
- I need to set each time the object key for the specific string available in the `IStringLocalizer`
- If I change a string key, I also need to update all the files manually.

What I'm looking for:

I'm looking for a solution that automatically fills the `Lang` object with all the properties available in the `.resx` file loaded in the current `View`. 
I guess the best place for handle this is `_Layout`.

Someone could help me?

Comment: did you consider creating a tool (i.e. via nodejs/or maybe even a gulp task), which will execute during the build and generate a static js file for every language? Though be aware that the C# string format syntax is unlikely applicable to javascript

Comment: @Tseng yep, but I honestly don't like this approach, I would like to generate a script object on the fly or something like a cookie